# Python Pandas : Transform a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with single column 'positions' which contains list of dictionaries. Here is how it looks:

```
df1.head()

    positions
0   []
1   [{'last_sale_price': 121.98, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': Equity(0 [GLD]), 'amount': 271}, {'last_sale_price': 280.245, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': Equity(1 [SPY]), 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 121.666, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': Equity(2 [TLT]), 'amount': 248}]
2   [{'last_sale_price': 121.8, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': Equity(0 [GLD]), 'amount': 271}, {'last_sale_price': 280.686, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': Equity(1 [SPY]), 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 120.61200000000001, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': Equity(2 [TLT]), 'amount': 248}]
3   [{'last_sale_price': 122.11, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': Equity(0 [GLD]), 'amount': 271}, {'last_sale_price': 281.43, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': Equity(1 [SPY]), 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 120.953, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': Equity(2 [TLT]), 'amount': 248}]
4   [{'last_sale_price': 121.98, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': Equity(0 [GLD]), 'amount': 271}, {'last_sale_price': 282.793, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': Equity(1 [SPY]), 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 121.11, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': Equity(2 [TLT]), 'amount': 248}]
```

I would like to extract the tickers and their amounts. Final output dataframe should look like :

```
   GLD  SPY  TLT
0  271  129  248
1  271  129  248
2  271  129  248
```

Here is what I have so far, but its not in the right format yet. I also think there is a better way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df1.positions = df1.positions.str.replace('(Equity)(\(\d+\s\[[a-zA-Z]+\]\))', "'" + r"\1\2" + "'", regex = True)
s = df1.positions.apply(eval)
s1 = s.tolist()
consolidate = []
for l in list(chain(*s1)):
    temp = {}
    for k,(key, value) in enumerate(l.items()) :
        temp.update({f"col{k+1}":key,
                     f"col{k+1}_val":value})
    consolidate.append(temp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(consolidate)

df2 = df2[['col3_val', 'col4_val']].rename(columns = {'col3_val': 'ticker', 'col4_val':'amount'})
df2.ticker = df2.ticker.str.replace(r'(Equity\(\d+\s\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(\]\))', r'\2')
df3 = df2.pivot( columns='ticker', values='amount')
df3.head()

ticker  GLD SPY TLT
0   271.0   NaN NaN
1   NaN 129.0   NaN
2   NaN NaN 248.0
3   271.0   NaN NaN
4   NaN 129.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

For ease of doing, I replaced Equity(0 [GLD]) to 'GLD' and changed few values.
Simple apply function with dict comprehension will do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{ 'positions':[ [],
[{'last_sale_price': 121.98, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': 'GLD', 'amount': 271}, {'last_sale_price': 280.245, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': 'SPY', 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 121.666, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': 'TLT', 'amount': 248}],
[{'last_sale_price': 121.8, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': 'GLD', 'amount': 281}, {'last_sale_price': 280.686, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': 'SPY', 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 120.61200000000001, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': 'TLT', 'amount': 248}],
[{'last_sale_price': 122.11, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': 'GLD', 'amount': 291}, {'last_sale_price': 281.43, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': 'SPY', 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 120.953, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': 'TLT', 'amount': 248}],
[{'last_sale_price': 121.98, 'cost_basis': 122.04199000000001, 'sid': 'GLD', 'amount': 261}, {'last_sale_price': 282.793, 'cost_basis': 280.38612250000006, 'sid': 'SPY', 'amount': 129}, {'last_sale_price': 121.11, 'cost_basis': 121.72783299999999, 'sid': 'TLT', 'amount': 248}]]} )

df1['positions'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series({x['sid']:x['amount'] for x in row}))

Out[28]: 
     GLD    SPY    TLT
0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  271.0  129.0  248.0
2  281.0  129.0  248.0
3  291.0  129.0  248.0
4  261.0  129.0  248.0
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your solution by first removing Equity part. But I get an error when I run second line of your solution . ```df1.positions = df1.positions.str.replace(r'(Equity\(\d+\s\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(\]\))', "'" + r"\2" + "'", regex = True)

df1['positions'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series({x['sid']:x['amount'] for x in row}))```. Error is ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: Understand the gist of approach in converting to dataframe from list. Check df1 after your replace command..you should be able to fix.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me (with help from @Siva)

```
df1.positions = df1.positions.str.replace(r'(Equity\(\d+\s\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(\]\))', " '" + r"\2" + "'", regex = True)
#convert positions to list
s = df1.positions.apply(eval).tolist()
#creating temp dataframe with the list
temp = pd.DataFrame({'positions': s })
#finally creating final output format
df2 = temp['positions'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series({x['sid']:x['amount'] for x in row}))
```